# Can we define an operation on the set of natural numbers with which the addition (+) can be described?

Tags: linear-algebra

On the set of natural numbers, we can define the operation $+$ as:

$m + 0 = m$

m + $n^+ = (m+n)^+$

($\forall m,n \in \mathbb{N}$)

With this operation, we can define the operation $\cdot$ as:

$m \cdot 0 = 0$

$m \cdot n^+ = m\cdot n+m$

With $\cdot$, we can define the operation $\text{^}$ and so on and so on.

My question is: Is there any basic operation $\circ$ (by basic, I mean that $\circ$ does not use any other operations) with which $+$ can be defined and that is not equal to $+$?

My second question is: Can we define a basic operation $\circ \neq +$ with which $\cdot$ can be defined?

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of addition is in fact using the successor function.  Your superscript $+$ is really successor, which is not addition.  The Peano axioms take successor as an undefined function, then define addition from it just as you did.